# I'm designing a router, I need some help

Tags: rf, wifi, manufacturing, router

Steps so far:

1. Looking to design a router.
2. Too hard, gave up.
3. Buying it from a router odm, oem.

My weird problems, and I tried googling a bit to no avail.

1. Why are chips so difficult to find, I mean mediatek chipsets barely have a product page for certain older chips.
2. Why are the datasheets non-existent?
3. Why is there no sdk or publicly available code from the manufacturer?
4. Why are the prices so expensive? I mean I found a distributor called "Ovaga" they're selling me one of three chips I need for the price of the assembled router from the oem. What insane economies of scale are at play here?

My simple problemS

1. I'll buy these routerboards from them in quantities of 100-200, how do I flash them when they get here in the most efficient way?
2. Is there any way their software could corrupt or access mine? I understand bootloaders on a certain basic level, how could i make sure I erase all their code?

A link to the routerboard

- https://www.hlktech.net/index.php?id=1175

I'm looking for a long winded rant from a experienced individual who's actually dealt with these problems, I'm sorry if my questions don't make sense. Thank you for your time, any advise is appreciated.

Comment: As it stands this question is not really suited to the stack exchange Q&A format, which lends itself more to specific questions rather than long winded rants. But long story short - keeping their IP behind an NDA wall weeds out the the little guy, so they only have to offer support to people who are likely to be ordering 10k+ of their chips. The weird distributors selling small Qtys at high prices are usually selling grey market parts (left-overs assembly houses have from big production runs) and can charge whatever they want because they know the non-production customers have no other choice.

Comment: Hey Tom, you seem a lot nicer than the guys over on reddit. Where would I post this to get feedback from the community? 

How can I even design the product without the datasheets? I can get funding and money behind me but until I actually build it how do I outright order the parts?

Comment: Is the [OpenWrt/LEDE project](https://openwrt.org/about) project any help? As for ``How can I even design the product without the datasheets?`` as a low-volume user I think the only option is to select components for which datasheets, and software examples/drivers, are available.

Comment: Definitely what Chester says. @MustansirGodhrawala router SoCs are far too complex to reverse-engineer them to make use of them. You need access to a datasheet. Ask yourself: assuming someone had the capital to fund your router business, why would it be a good idea to choose your as OEM instead of one of the large OEMs which already know how to build routers, unlike you, and who get much much cheaper parts, being much larger (economies of scale)? You'll probably find that it only makes sense for very specific use cases, where no other OEM has anything comparable in stock – and then price …

Comment: … probably won't matter as much (if you're building, say, specialized routerfor some industrial application, whether it costs 10€ or 1500€ won't matter much, but whether it has high reliability and a support person that will be in the factory 8 hours later if necessary matters). If price matters, you're not going to beat mass production, so you'd want to find a different market niche! For experimentations, there are *plenty* Linux SoCs / System on Modules you can buy with documentation.

Comment: Following on from what Marcus says, another application where specialised routers maybe required are for secure networks. E.g. see [FCC Bans Sale of New Devices From Chinese Companies Huawei, ZTE and Others](https://cset.georgetown.edu/article/fcc-bans-sale-of-new-devices-from-chinese-companies-huawei-zte-and-others/) and [List of Equipment and Services Covered By Section 2 of The Secure Networks Act](https://www.fcc.gov/supplychain/coveredlist). Given the need for a _secure supply chain_ not sure how easy it is to enter that market.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Impossible to enter that market as small player, if you still want cheap SoCs (otherwise, you'd still be buying HiSilicon, Rockchip…); and: that's by far not a niche use case; you'd be competing wih HP, Juniper, Cisco, and on the small end with AVM, Mikrotik, Ubiquity,…, so you'd still be outgunned on scale.